# Issue with todo counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

Hello I've got a basic todo going but I am having an issue where if user clicks on a todo item as completed and then deletes it, the counter showing how many todos are left decreases twice. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
let todoCounter = 0;
counterDisplay = document.querySelector('#todo-counter');

counterDisplay.textContent = `${todoCounter} todos left`;

document.querySelector('#new-todo').addEventListener('keypress', e =>
{
    text = e.target.value;

    if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13)
  {
    addTodo(text);
    todoCounter++;
    counterDisplay.textContent = `${todoCounter} todos left`;
  }
});

const addTodo = text =>
{
    const todoEl = document.createElement('li');
  const todoText = document.createTextNode(text);
  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  todoEl.appendChild(todoText);
  todoEl.appendChild(deleteButton);
  const todoDom = document.querySelector('#todos');
  todoDom.appendChild(todoEl);
};

document.querySelector('#todos').addEventListener('click', e =>
{
    target = e.target;
  if (!target.matches('button'))
  {
    if(target.matches('li'))
    {
        target.classList.toggle('completed');

      if (target.classList.contains('completed'))
      {
        todoCounter--;
            counterDisplay.textContent = `${todoCounter} todos left`;
      }
      else
      {
        todoCounter++;
        counterDisplay.textContent = `${todoCounter} todos left`;
      }
    }
    return;
  }

  target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(target.parentNode);

  todoCounter--;
    counterDisplay.textContent = `${todoCounter} todos left`;
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dk5690/aLn310y2/

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your `if` statement when `true` triggers the `.completed` CSS Class and the `todoCounter` is either decremented or incremented (toggles as you click on the `li` tag), when it's decremented there's no (code) to check if the parent node is in the `completed` state, not to decrement the counter twice for the same todo when the delete `button` is clicked.

Here's the code fragment that you could add to ensure the `completed` state of the parent node (i.e the `li` tag) is checked. The fragment should be added immediately after your `if` statement closing tag, and the rest of the code after that deleted.

```
else if (target.matches('button') && target.parentNode.classList.contains('completed')) {
                target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(target.parentNode);
            }
            else if (target.matches('button')) {
                target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(target.parentNode);
                todoCounter--;
                counterDisplay.textContent = `${todoCounter} todos left`;
            }
```

Below is the code refactored and running:

```js
   let todoCounter = 0;
   counterDisplay = document.querySelector('#todo-counter');

   counterDisplay.textContent = `${todoCounter} todos left`;

   document.querySelector('#new-todo').addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    text = e.target.value;

    if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13) {
     addTodo(text);
     todoCounter++;
     counterDisplay.textContent = `${todoCounter} todos left`;

     document.getElementById('new-todo').value = '';
    }
   });

   const addTodo = text => {
    const todoEl = document.createElement('li');
    const todoText = document.createTextNode(text);
    let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    // and give it some content
    let deleteContent = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    // add the text node to the newly created button
    deleteButton.appendChild(deleteContent);
    todoEl.appendChild(todoText);
    todoEl.appendChild(deleteButton);
    const todoDom = document.querySelector('#todos');
    todoDom.appendChild(todoEl);
   };

   document.querySelector('#todos').addEventListener('click', e => {
    target = e.target;

    if (target.matches('li')) {
     target.classList.toggle('completed');

     if (target.classList.contains('completed')) {
      todoCounter--;
      counterDisplay.textContent = `${todoCounter} todos left`;
     }
     else {
      todoCounter++;
      counterDisplay.textContent = `${todoCounter} todos left`;
     }
    }
    else if (target.matches('button') && target.parentNode.classList.contains('completed')) {
     target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(target.parentNode);
    }
    else if (target.matches('button')) {
     target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(target.parentNode);
     todoCounter--;
     counterDisplay.textContent = `${todoCounter} todos left`;
    }
   });
```

```css
.completed {
            text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Todo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="todo-counter"></div>
        <input type="text" id="new-todo"/>
        <ul id="todos"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: IMO you should provide more information than "The problem was in an if statement" considering there are a few. You should also explain why what they did caused an issue so they can learn from it rather than just learn to copy and paste a solution

Comment: Thanks @Marie , considering the fact I'm kinda new to Stackoverflow, I promise to be more detailed next time I'm giving a solution. Thanks again (:

Comment: Well, welcome to SO. Keep in mind StackOverflow is a QA archive. Your goal should not just be to help the OP but to help future developers with similar issues. With that in mind you can and should edit this answer to provide more details.

Comment: I've edited my answer Marie, lemme know what you think. Thanks again.